# android button setonclicklistener

Tags: android, if-statement, button, onclicklistener

I am new on Android programming. This is my MainActivty.java and layout file .I press the buttons but  sometimes it works sometimes doesn't. What is the problem here? Thanks for your help

mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button mix,verb,noun,adjective,adverb,meaning;
TextView screen, result, checkmeaning;
ExpandableListView list;
String[] vocabulary = { "open", "computer", "get up", "good", "carefully" };
String[] vocabularyType = { "verb", "noun", "verb", "adjective", "adverb" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupButtons();


}



public int karistir() {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int sayi;
    sayi = rnd.nextInt(vocabulary.length);
    return sayi;
}

private void setupButtons() {
    list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    screen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screen);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    checkmeaning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    verb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    noun = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    adjective= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    adverb= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    meaning= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    verb.setOnClickListener(this);
    noun.setOnClickListener(this);
    adjective.setOnClickListener(this);
    adverb.setOnClickListener(this);
    meaning.setOnClickListener(this);
    mix.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        if (mix.isPressed()) {
            result.setText("");
            screen.setText("");
            int i = karistir();
            screen.setText(vocabulary[i]);
}

        else if (verb.isPressed()){
            int x = Arrays.binarySearch(vocabulary, screen.getText());

            if(vocabularyType[x]=="verb"){
                result.setText("TRUE");
            }

        }
        else if (noun.isPressed()){
            int x = Arrays.binarySearch(vocabulary, screen.getText());

            if(vocabularyType[x]=="noun"){
                result.setText("TRUE");
            }

        }
        else if( adjective.isPressed()){
            int x = Arrays.binarySearch(vocabulary, screen.getText());

            if(vocabularyType[x]=="adjective"){
                result.setText("TRUE");
            }

        }
        else if (adverb.isPressed()){
            int x = Arrays.binarySearch(vocabulary, screen.getText());

            if(vocabularyType[x]=="adverb"){
                result.setText("TRUE");
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

layout file

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/result"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="New Vocabulary"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Verb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Noun" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Adjective" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Adverb" />

    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32374973/4385913) and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method instead of yours :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int IdButton = v.getId();
    switch (IdButton){
        case R.id.button:
            //Do stuff
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
            //Do stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Otherwise add on every `Button` in your xml the `android:onClick="NounClick"` (Example) and in yout code should be :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="NounClick"
        android:text="Noun" />
```

And the method should be like :

```
public void NounClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NounClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // does something very interesting
}
```

**By the way** if you use my last option make sure that you remove this :

```
verb.setOnClickListener(this);
noun.setOnClickListener(this);
adjective.setOnClickListener(this);
adverb.setOnClickListener(this);
meaning.setOnClickListener(this);
mix.setOnClickListener(this);
```

### FINAL EDIT

Your problem is not aobut the `CLICKS` if you had had debug the code you'd know that when you press in a wrong answer your index is -1 as = `length=5; index=-1`
So I've changed your code a little bit and I improved your "Game", take a look.

Your `onClick()` method should be like :

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            switch (v.getId()) {

```
            case R.id.start:
                gamestart = true;
                result.setText("");
                screen.setText("");
                IndexQuestion = karistir();
                screen.setText(vocabulary[IndexQuestion]);
                Log.d("LLETRA i", String.valueOf(IndexQuestion));
                break;
            case R.id.button1:
                if(gamestart) {
                    if (vocabularyType[IndexQuestion].equals("verb")) {
                        result.setText("TRUE");
                    } else {
                        result.setText("FALSE");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                if(gamestart) {
                    if (vocabularyType[IndexQuestion].equals("noun")) {
                        result.setText("TRUE");
                    } else {
                        result.setText("FALSE");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                if(gamestart) {
                    if (vocabularyType[IndexQuestion].equals("adjective")) {
                        result.setText("TRUE");
                    } else {
                        result.setText("FALSE");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                if(gamestart) {
                    if (vocabularyType[IndexQuestion].equals("adverb")) {
                        result.setText("TRUE");
                    } else {
                        result.setText("FALSE");
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

And you've to create a global variable named `IndexQuestion` that is the index of the question.
I've added a global variable also for know if the game is started because when I click on a verb when is no question it would say "TRUE" or "FALSE" and I avoid it.
Create those Global Variables :

```
int IndexQuestion;
Boolean gamestart = false;
```

*Note: This is just a skeleton of your game, you can change it as you like it*

Comment: @fatih It's not posible, I just copy&pasted your code and it works for me with both methods. Please update the code.... you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you:))) It works I am going to improve it and I'll use it in my class. Thank you so much again:)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `button.ispressed()` use `v.getid()` in `onclick()` method and use switch statement with case of id's of buttons like below :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.start :
     //Do whatever you want to do here
     break;
     case R.id.button1:
     //Do whatever you want to do here
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First point:**

Don't use `verb.isPressed()` to determine what button was pressed.

Use the view id:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {

    }else if(...){} // and so on
```

**Second point:**

This is wrong:

```
 if(vocabularyType[y]=="noun")
```

When comparing Strings you should use String.equals() like so:

```
 if(vocabularyType[y].equals("noun"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set OnClickListeners like this:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new    Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //Do something
    }
    });
```

Just put it on your onCreate method

Comment: I used "onclicklistener implementation" Aren't they same?

Answer (score 0):

```
audioimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
//Do Something
}
catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I used "onclicklistener implementation" Aren't they same?

Comment: same but little bit of confused try above mentioned code@fatih

Comment: I have tried but Unfortunately the result is same. I think the problem isn't clicklistener. Thanks for your effort.